# Encrypted Ubuntu install fails to see bootable media

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, encryption

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Tablet. I chose the encryption option when I installed.

I'm now trying to live-boot from the Ubuntu install disk so I can re-size my Ubuntu partition. However, with the USB inserted, I see no option to boot from the USB. Originally my thought was that Grub was configured to ignore it, so I updated `/etc/default/grub`, which now reads as follows:

```
/ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

I do now at least see a Grub menu while booting, but it has no entry for the install disk. I'm not sure why my bootloader wouldn't be seeing it--when I escape down in to the Lenovo UEFI, it *does* show the USB as a bootable option. However, whenever I select the option from Lenovo's UEFI, it instead boots in to my existing, on-disk Ubuntu install.

I'm not quite sure where to go from here. I don't have very detailed knowledge of the interaction between the Lenovo UEFI and the GRUB2 install Ubuntu defaulted to. I don't know if Cryptsetup is complicating the matter at all, either.